# How to identifiy criss cross merges in Git and Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial, merge, git-merge

I'd like to identify the number of [criss cross merges](http://web.archive.org/web/20090805232313/http://wiki.vestasys.org/MergingFuture/Food4Thought/TrickyCases) that exists in some Git and Mercurial open source projects for research purposes only. Any suggestions about how to accomplish this?

A criss cross merge could be determined if a merge has two different common ancestors. It is being developed a new merge strategy to Mercurial called [consensus merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConsensusMerge) which will have the ancestor.ancestor() code extended to return all greatest common ancestors. I couldn't find this new piece of code yet, but it will help a lot.

I don't know Git enough but it certainly has something similar.

Comment: That's an interesting link, but over 6 years old... I wonder what a new/revised version (with more Hg/Git/Bzr input) would look like...

Comment: You might want to rename the title to say “3-way merge” instead because I never heard “criss cross merge” anywhere before…

Comment: @poke, read the link.  3-way merge != criss cross merge.  Criss cross merge is when branch A merges branch B changes, and branch B merges branch A changes.  Using 3-way merge at a later point of A->B or B->A can result in errors in the merge process.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh, sorry, just read the first sentence there and it sounded like it was the same.

Comment: Mercurial revsets are very expressive. I’m sure you can find a way to identify these kind of merges with them. `hg help revsets`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get the number of criss-cross merges between any branches in a repository, not the number of times two branches haven been criss-cross merged. In that case the following shell script should do for Git:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the list of branches and convert it to an array.
branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)
branches=( $branches )
N=${#branches[*]}

cc_merges=0

# Loop over all combinations of two branches.
for ((i=0; i<N-1; ++i)); do
    for ((k=i+1; k<N; ++k)); do
        a=${branches[$i]}
        b=${branches[$k]}
        bases=$(git merge-base --all $a $b | wc -l)
        if [ $bases -gt 1 ]; then
            let "cc_merges += 1"
        fi
    done
done

echo "Number of criss-cross merges in repository: $cc_merges"
```

For Mercurial, both its `ancestor()` revset and the `debugancestor` command unfortunately only list the greatest common ancestor, not a list of all ancestors, so I'm unable to suggest a solution here.